# assertEquals() with HashSet

Tags: java, unit-testing, hashset

I have a constructor for the class of player

```
public Player(String name, String playerDescription,
        HashSet<String> abilities) {

            this.name = name;
            this.playerDescription;
            this.abilities = abilities;
}
```

I create an instance of this class

```
Player p = new Player ("Jon Snow", "Brave Swordsman", new HashSet<String>());
```

I've created an `addAbilities()` method, to add to the `HashSet`.

```
public void addAbilities(String newAbility) {
    abilities.add(newAbility);
}
```

However, when I go to test the method (using a get method)

```
public String getAbility() {
    String abilityString = abilities.toString();

    return abilityString;
}
```

My test :

```
@Test
public void testAddAbility() {
Player p = new Player("Jon Snow", "Brave Swordsman", new HashSet<String>());

    s.addAbility("Leadership"); 
    assertEquals("Leadership", s.getAbility());
}
```

I get an difference in the test output.

Comparison failure: expected: `<[Leadership]>` but was `<[[Leadership]]>`

My question is, why is there a difference in output and is it good practice to make a `HashSet` this way?

Comment: Because you're converting the entire set to string, you should instead have a method like `Player#hasAbility(String)` which calls `abilities#contains`

Comment: I can't immediately see why the output is wrong, but to address something else, are you sure you need to have the constructor accept a Hash set? Couldn't you just create one inside the constructor?

Comment: Do not declare arguments or variable as `HashSet`. Use only `Set`, as the implementation might change... Also, for predefined abilities use `enum`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HashSet.toString()` returns a String displaying the elements inside `[]` (and with `,` character between them).

So in your assertion you compare `Leadership` to `[Leadership]`.

This would be ok for the assertion :

```
assertEquals("[Leadership]", s.getAbility());
```

But I think that you should rather change the method to retrieve abilities.
Is it a retrieval and formatting method ?
Rename the method in this sense.

Otherwise, keep the `Set` abstraction and just return the `Set` as it is :

```
public Set<String> getAbilities(){
  return abilities;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The format for a Set toString output is "[item1, item2, ...]". You only have one item, so it's "[item1]".

I'd suggest you make this method

```
public Set<String> getAbilities()
```

Or better yet

```
public Set<Ability> getAbilities()
```

Answer (score 0):

your code has potentially flaws at a couple of points, the first one is

ability is a collection, so this getter is not correct because it returns a String

```
public String getAbility() {
    String abilityString = abilities.toString();

    return abilityString;
}
```

so that "getter" is giving back a string that java JDK developers can change without even inform anybody... as a concecuense of that

the @test is failing....

you should return a (an unmodifiable) collection in the getter and from that check whether the string value is present...

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>();
mySet.add("Leader");
mySet.contains("Leader");
```

now you are indeendent of what is happening in the future with the toString implementation of the hashSet

Answer (score 0):

I suggest removing the `getAbility()` method and adding:

```
public boolean hasAbility(String ability) {
    return abilities.contains(ability);
}
```

as for testing the addition method, you can do this:

```
@Test
public void testAddAbility() {
    Player p = new Player("Jon Snow", "Brave Swordsman", new HashSet<String>());
    p.addAbility("Leadership"); 

    assertTrue(p.hasAbility("Leadership"));
}
```